# embeding a joomla module in a component

Tags: joomla, module

I want to show a module in a component in joomla-2.5. 
I tried below code but it is not working.

```
jimport('joomla.application.module.helper');
$modules = JModuleHelper::getModules('latest albums'); 
foreach($modules as $module)
{
echo JModuleHelper::renderModule($module);
}
```

'latest albums' is the title of my module.
Also I used mod_name alone and also (mod_name,mod title) together but they didn't work.

How can I resolve it.
Thanks

Comment: Now it is working after I has changed it like below but it is showing a half of the module. 'jimport('joomla.application.module.helper');
$module = JModuleHelper::getModule('mod_muscol_featured_albums'); 
echo JModuleHelper::renderModule($module);'

Comment: what do you mean "half of the module"?

Comment: This module is an image slider but in this way it is showing just its buttons.

Comment: check source in firebig, html is maybe there, but the path is missing. check if js which module uses is loaded, look at error console as well